# Matrices of nodes in Tikz alike to the ones in the amsmath package

Tags: tikz-pgf, amsmath, tikz-matrix

I'm trying to work with matrices in Tikz. Specífically I would like to follow the amsmath package but I'm having a really hard time dealing with the overlay - remember picture thing. Here is the example I'm stuck with right now:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{luatex85} 


\newcommand{\overlay}[2][]{\tikz[overlay, remember picture, #1]{#2}}
\newcommand{\flag}[2]{\overlay[baseline=(#1.base)] {\node (#1) {$#2$};}}

 \begin{document}

 \[
 M_5 = \begin{pmatrix}
\flag{a11}{a_{11}} & \flag{a12}{a_{12}} & \flag{a13}{a_{13}} & \flag{a1}{a_{14}} & \flag{a15}{a_{15}}\\
\flag{a21}{a_{21}} & \flag{a22}{a_{22}} & \flag{a23}{a_{23}} & \flag{a24}{a_{24}} & \flag{a25}{a_{25}} \\
\flag{a31}{a_{31}} & \flag{a32}{a_{32}} & \flag{a33}{a_{33}} & \flag{a34}{a_{34}} & \flag{a35}{a_{35}} \\
16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 2\\ 
\end{pmatrix} \]
\end{document}
```

This code perfectly prints a matrix, except it's a little different than the way the amsmath package do. Here is the comparison:

[image]

So I guess my first question would be how can I modify my code to make them look alike.

Also, if I follow this method, even if I decided just to leave the matrices as such, there's a big problem and I don't understand why this is happening. If I modify the previous code, just speaking about the matrix data, then the resultant matrix is a complete disaster. For example to get the matrix that is obtained by eliminating the last raw, either putting the last raw as a comment or getting eliminated produces a really messy matrix:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the same matrix, don't use the `overlay` option and add the `inner sep=0` option to your nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{luatex85} 


\newcommand{\overlay}[2][]{\tikz[remember picture, #1]{#2}}
\newcommand{\flag}[2]{\overlay[baseline=(#1.base)] {\node[inner sep=0] (#1) {$#2$};}}

 \begin{document}

 \[
 M_5 = \begin{pmatrix}
\flag{a11}{a_{11}} & \flag{a12}{a_{12}} & \flag{a13}{a_{13}} & \flag{a1}{a_{14}} & \flag{a15}{a_{15}}\\
\flag{a21}{a_{21}} & \flag{a22}{a_{22}} & \flag{a23}{a_{23}} & \flag{a24}{a_{24}} & \flag{a25}{a_{25}} \\
\flag{a31}{a_{31}} & \flag{a32}{a_{32}} & \flag{a33}{a_{33}} & \flag{a34}{a_{34}} & \flag{a35}{a_{35}} \\
16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 2\\ 
\end{pmatrix} \]

\def\flag#1#2{#2}
 \[
 M_5 = \begin{pmatrix}
\flag{a11}{a_{11}} & \flag{a12}{a_{12}} & \flag{a13}{a_{13}} & \flag{a1}{a_{14}} & \flag{a15}{a_{15}}\\
\flag{a21}{a_{21}} & \flag{a22}{a_{22}} & \flag{a23}{a_{23}} & \flag{a24}{a_{24}} & \flag{a25}{a_{25}} \\
\flag{a31}{a_{31}} & \flag{a32}{a_{32}} & \flag{a33}{a_{33}} & \flag{a34}{a_{34}} & \flag{a35}{a_{35}} \\
16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 2\\ 
\end{pmatrix} \]
\end{document}
```